# Вывод данных из SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Пытаюсь вывести структурированный список из таблицы. Вместо данных выводит все подряд, но не данные.

Вот код:

```
  <?php
        $mysqli = new mysqli ('localhost', 'root', 'Admin', 'novartis');
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
        {
          echo "Извините возникла проблема на сайте";
          echo "Ошибка: Не удалось создать соединение с базой MySQL и вот почему: \n";
          echo "Номер ошибки:".$mysqli->connect_errno."\n";
          echo "Ошибка:".$mysqli->connect_error."\n";
          exit;
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `sandoz`";
        if (!$run = $mysqli->query($sql))
        {
          echo "Извините, возникла проблема в работе сайта";
          echo "Ошибка: Наш запрос не удался и вот почему: \n";
          echo "Запрос:".$sql."\n";
          echo "Номер_ошибки".$mysqli->errno."\n";
          echo "Ошибка:".$mysqli->error."\n";
          exit;
        }
        $result = array();
        if ($run && mysqli_num_rows($run) !=0)
        {
          while ($rs = $run->fetch_assoc())
           {
            $result[] = $rs;
           }
        }
        $tbody = ' ';
        foreach($result as $key=>$val)
        {
          $data = 'tr';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['Inventory_LLC'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['Inventory_DD'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['AssetCategory'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['AssetType'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['AssetSubtype'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['Transfer_Date'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['Return_Date'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['UniqID'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['Asset_Owner'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['Owner_Comp'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['Owner_Location'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['Owner_Status'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['Asset_Status'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['Asset_Entry'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['SN'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['Notes'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['CR_IMEI'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['Org_Unit'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['Position'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['Cost'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['Any_Val'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['Pur_Date'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['Check_Uncheck'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['Local_Material'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['PO'].'</td>';
          $data .= 'td'.$val['Activated'].'</td>';
          $data .= '</tr>';
        }
         ?>

         <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
        table {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        td, th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }
        </style>
          </head>
          <body>
            <table>
            <?=$data?>
            <tr>
              <th>Inventory_LLC</th>
              <th>Inventory_DD</th>
              <th>AssetCategory</th>
              <th>AssetType</th>
              <th>AssetSubtype</th>
              <th>Transfer_Date</th>
              <th>Return_Date</th>
              <th>UniqID</th>
              <th>Asset_Owner</th>
              <th>Owner_Comp</th>
              <th>Owner_Location</th>
              <th>Owner_Status</th>
              <th>Asset_Status</th>
              <th>SN</th>
              <th>Notes</th>
              <th>CR_IMEI</th>
              <th>Org_Unit</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Cost</th>
              <th>Any_Val</th>
              <th>Pur_Date</th>
              <th>Check_Uncheck</th>
              <th>Local_Material</th>
              <th>PO</th>
              <th>Activated</th>
            </tr>

<tr>
<?=$data?>
</tr>
            </table>
          </body>
          </html>
```

Comment: почему вместо `<td>` у вас просто `td` ?

Comment: ооооой, спасибо, мой завтык

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в цикле foreach пропустил скобки на операторах